# something wrong with the h.264 bytes?

Tags: c#, android, c++, mp4, h.264

I save h.264 using mediacodec(android) and open it using Elecard Stream analyzer
[image]

The StreamType is unknown

Is the data not correct?

The mp4 file can not play I open it there will be error:0xc00d36c4

I want to play it. But first I should fix the data error.

Comment: Why have you tagged c++, c# and android?

Comment: I wonder it if I can use c++ or c# to play it @kiner_shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its raw h246, the h246 itself looks good but,
its not **mp4**

mp4 is a **Container Format** where h246 or Audio (AAC) is embedded.

Rename File to .h246 and try to Play it with vlc

Comment: can i use c++ or c# to play it?

Comment: Sure you need to create an GUI Application where U decode the raw h246 with ffmpeg or gstreamer and Display the Decoded frames afterwards on your gui

Comment: can i decode it without ffmpeg or gstreamer?

Comment: U need a h246 Decoder where it comes does not matter ;)

Comment: win32 has decoder?

Comment: I dont know Google it :)